# Material option menu background

Tags: android

How to change the color of the top and bottom padding?

[image]

If I use

```
<item name="popupMenuBackground">@color/black</item>
```

The padding just disappears.

Answer (score 0):

padding disappears probably because original `popupMenuBackground` attribute is pointing on some drawable with built-in padding ([`<padding` tag](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource#Shape)). just don't use only color, make own drawable with padding and rounded corners